# Problem with Probability and MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution (bug?)

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Using the input

```
Probability[z[1] >= 1 && z[2] >= 1 && z[5] >= 1, 
  Array[z, 6] \[Distributed] MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[4, {4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0}]] // Short
```

Returned is

> 1/495 Hold[Function[{Compile`$$2072,<<4>>,Compile`$$2077},Boole[<<1>>]]][0,<<5>>]+<<14>>

Releasing the hold gives the correct result, but it appears there's an issue when there are zero elements in the count vector.

On 10.3.1 Windows. Works fine in 9.x Windows.

Confirmations?

Comment: Same on Windows 7 *Mathematica* 10.4.1 and essentially the same on Windows 7 *Mathematica* 11.0.1.  (By "essentially" I mean the `Function[{Compile...` doesn't show but the `Hold`'s show.)

Comment: Happens on 11.0 on Manjaro 16.10.3 too. Using ReleaseHold I get 32/55

Comment: Same behaviour Windows 10 Mathematica version 11

Comment: `ReleaseHold@
 Probability[z[1] >= 1 && z[2] >= 1 && z[5] >= 1, 
  Array[z, 6] \[Distributed] 
   MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[4, {4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0}]]` evaluates to 32/55

Comment: `NProbability` does give the correct result at least. (These things are probably "features", e.g. they check that user do not fall asleep solving problems in Mathematica...)